# Is there a way to force python ThreadPoolExecutor threads to use same request session?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, threadpoolexecutor

Below is a dummy client class for the pokemon API

```
class PokemonClient:
    def __init__(self, host: str):
        self.host = host
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def request(self, method: str, url: str, **kwargs):
        response = self.session.request(method, url, **kwargs)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json()

    def get(self, url: str, **kwargs: dict):
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    
    def get_pokemon(self, id: str):
        return self.get(os.path.join(self.host, 'api/v2/pokemon', id))
```

I'm trying to send multiple requests over the pokemon API and I'm using `ThreadPoolExecutor` and I see that for each thread, a new connection is created each time. Is there a way to make the threads use the same connection?

```
import logging
import os
import requests

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(message)s")
pokemon_url = 'https://pokeapi.co'
client = PokemonClient(pokemon_url)

pokemon_ids = range(1, 50)
def get_pokemon_id_mapping(id, cl):
    return (
        id,
        cl.get_pokemon(str(id))['name']
    )

with ThreadPoolExecutor(4) as pool:
    pokemons = list(
        pool.map(partial(get_pokemon_id_mapping, cl=client), pokemon_ids)
    )
```

output:

[image]

Comment: If they use the same session, they will need to serialize their requests, since a single session can only carry one request at a time.  It's normal to have one HTTP connection per thread, because network connections cannot, in general, be shared between threads.

Comment: It looks in your log like you have 4 HTTPS connections, which is expected, and you have 5 different requests; which seems to indicate the fifth request has reused the connection as expected.